# How to quickfix and build a bug in an NPM package, so it's available to the build server?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

Maybe this question is a bit off the rules. I'm using and npm package, which built in type definitions for TypeScript. Unfortunately there is a bug in the definitions, which I can easily fix.

I want to make this new version of the package available to my build server. First I thought I can just fork the repository on Github and add this repository as the source in my `package.json`, but then I realized that this package needs to be built.

So my question is, where should I go from here? Of course I've sent a pull request, but what can I do until this is merged and released? Should I clone the package and publish it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just forked the repo and build it with my fix included.
Then i used my github-fork in the package json.
(you can use github links with branch or tag annotations)

As soon as the merge was made i switched back to the original package.

Comment: What I additionally learned is that the `package.json` can even pin branches. Yarn supports it to: `yarn add https://github.com/yourusername/reponame#branchname`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package). It's just for this siatuation. Also, if you use pnpm, use `pnpm patch` to patch a package you are using.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34788633)

Answer (score 0):

I had quite similar problem with buggy type definitions. The steps to fix an npm package and then use are:

1. fork the package
2. create a new fix branch,
3. fix the bug, push to your forked repo,
4. point to the repo in your `package.json`,
5. create a pull request to help package maintainers

You can find more details here on my blog: https://www.kozubek.dev/2019/02/23/fixing-npm-package.html

Hope this helps!